# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Craft CMS breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          5
Users contacted                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            16        229
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                1          4
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         41        188
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               32        108
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                84        548
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               62         85
Questions reopened                                1          0
Questions protected                               0          2
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0         41
Questions closed                                 82         11
Question flags handled⁴                          18         23
Posts unlocked                                    0          3
Posts undeleted                                   1         15
Posts locked                                      0         13
Posts deleted⁵                                   83        495
Posts bumped                                      0        440
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  0        422
Comments deleted⁶                                13        578
Comment flags handled                            66        356
Answers flagged                                   2        311
Answer flags handled                            193        120
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...